# TableSorter Math widget and Scroller widget not working together

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter, jquery-widgets

I'm trying to use the TableSorter Math Widget and Scroller Widget together but they don't seem to work while both active. When both active, the scroller is the only one that works. When I disable the scroller, the math one works. Is there any fix to this or has this just not been patched yet?

Specifically, I'm using the Math widget to calculate the column totals/column means of each of the columns in my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scroller widget creates up to four clones of the table when initialized. It has not yet been optimized to work with all the other widgets, especially widgets that manipulate the table content, like the math widget.

I have created a new issue (https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/957) so that you can keep track of the progress on making these widgets compatible.

Comment: Ok, awesome. Thank you Mottie. I appreciate all of the work you've done. Cheers! :)